# Village Sticker

Tags: vehicle, illinois

Can a village issue a fine for not having a vehicle sticker without issuing a citation?
The village clerk where I live issued a letter stating that if I do not pay for the over due sticker and the fine, the fine will go up to $150.00. I thought the local police department would have to issue a citation in order for a violation to have accured? This letter stated the village checked with the Sec. of State to make sure I lived in that village.

Comment: Where? This is an issue that would vary dramatically from one place to the next. It implicates both local government organization and detailed vehicle registration laws.

Comment: Oak Lawn Illinois

Comment: Why would a police department citation be necessary?  With a parking violation, for example, the officer has to certify that he or she observed the violation.  In this case, that is not necessary because the fact that you do not have a sticker can readily be established by referring to the village's records.

Comment: Oh ok. Tthats exactly what I wanted to know. I wasn't sure if a ticket was necessary. Thanks.